# Auto Scrolling Windows Form for Dynamic Content

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop-application, tablelayoutpanel

I'm working on C# .NET 3.5 desktop application. In the software I have a `Form`, which contains a `TableLayoutPanel` `tp1`. The 2nd row of the `tp1` contains a `GroupBox`. The `GroupBox` contains another `TableLayoutPanel` `tp2`. `tp2` will grow dynamically during runtime.

```
Form
-----------------------------
|  TableLayoutPanel tp1      |
|____________________________|
|    GroupBox                |
|    ________________________|
|   |                        |
|   |  TableLayoutPanel tp2  |
|   |  ______________________|
|   | |                      |
|   | |   Dynamic content    |
|   | |        here          |
|   | |                      |
|   | |______________________|
|   |________________________|
|                            |
|____________________________|
-----------------------------
```

The AutoScroll of the `Form` is true.

The SizeType of Row 2 of `tp1` is AutoSize.

The AutoSize of the `GroupBox` is true.

The AutoSize of `tp2` is true. `tp2` is dynamically updated by the following code:

```
tp2.RowCount = tp2.RowCount + 1;
tp2.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
gb.BackColor = Color.Red;
tp2.Controls.Add(gb, 0, tp2.RowCount - 1);
```

I want a scrollbars to appear in the `Form` when `tp1` is larger than the window size. But no scrollbar is appearing.

I can activate scrollbars in the same way if I set AutoScroll to true for `tp1`. But I want the scrollbars on the `Form`, not `tp1`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform such settings using designer or code:

```
var panel1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
panel1.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
panel1.RowCount = 2;
panel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 20));
panel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
panel1.AutoSize = true;
panel1.AutoSizeMode= System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

var groupBox1 = new GroupBox() { Text = "GroupBox" };
groupBox1.AutoSize = true;
groupBox1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

var panel2 = new TableLayoutPanel() {Top= 24, Left= 5 };
panel2.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
panel2.AutoSize = true;
panel2.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

groupBox1.Controls.Add(panel2);

panel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Label" });
panel1.Controls.Add(groupBox1);

this.SuspendLayout();
this.Controls.Add(panel1);
this.AutoScroll = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    panel2.RowCount += 1;
    panel2.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
    panel2.Controls.Add(new GroupBox()
    {
        Text = string.Format("GroupBox{0}", i + 1)
    });
}
this.ResumeLayout(true);
```

And this would be the result:

[image]

Comment: I got my problem solved way before this answer. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Great! You're welcome and thanks for the feedback :)